# How to pass multiple arguments in a function when passed in async

Tags: c++, asynchronous, parameter-passing

I want to pass two arguments for a function that takes two arguments as parameters when that function is passed in an async function. I have never used async ever before so I don't know how to do this

So this is the function

```
double NearestPoints::otherCoordinate(Coordinate coordinate1, Coordinate** secondCoordinate){
```

This is the async function

```
std::future<double> ret = std::async(&otherCoordinate,coordinate1,ref(coordinate2));
```

I am pretty sure I am implementing the function in the wrong way,but I just want to know the correct implementation.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <future>      


int add(int x,int y) {    
    return x+y;
}

int main()
{  
    std::future<int> fut = std::async(add, 10,20);
    int ret = fut.get();
    std::cout << ret << std::endl;       
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `otherCoordinate` is a member function. An instance of `NearestPoints` needs to be passed in as well.

Comment: I am not calling async in main . I am calling it in a for loop of another function and that function is also a member function of NearestPoints

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from your question it looks like you have forgotten to pass a `NearestPoints` instance to your `std::async` call. Since `NearestPoints::otherCoordinate` is a member function it needs an instance of the `NearestPoints` class passed for its `this` pointer.

To fix this you should pass in a copy of the current instance so that the function has access to an instance with which to operate on.

Your fixed call to `std::async` would look like this:

```
std::future<double> ret = std::async(&NearestPoints::otherCoordinate, *this, coordinate1, std::ref(coordinate2));
```

Comment: When I tried that it gave me this error : '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression

Comment: My bad, you need to put the class name before the member function name, even if your function is within the class scope. Fixed.

Comment: Now it's giving these two errors . Error 1: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)' NearestPoints. Error 2: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::future<unknown-type>' to 'std::future<double>' NearestPoints

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why the return type is ambiguous. To fix the apparent ambiguity what I've done is to specify the type of the function pointer explicitly to resolve any possible ambiguity. See my updated answer.

Comment: Still giving the same error . One more thing . I am calling the async in another member function of NearestPoints not in the main

Comment: I am unable to duplicate that error. See [here](https://ideone.com/eIJosf) for a (contrived) working example.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your call as follows :

```
std::future<double> ret = std::async(&NearestPoints::otherCoordinate,&instance_name,coordinate1,std::ref(coordinate2));
```